# Updating Django Rest Framework nested ForeignKey

Tags: django-rest-framework

Please I need help updating an object' foreign key. How can I achieve this

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Employee(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='employee')
    code = models.CharField()
```

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    person = PersonSerializer()
    code = serializers.IntegerField

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own update method to make sure the nested data is updated correctly.

See the documentation of Django REST framework at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-update-methods-for-nested-representations